# Codeception requests returning unexpected responses?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, codeception

I am trying to test my API using Codeception and I am testing every end endpoint. My tests look like so:

```
<?php 
$faker = Faker\Factory::create();

$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('create a new user');
$I->useToken();
$I->sendPost('users', [
    "first_name"    => "Test",
    "last_name"     => "Test",
    "email"         => 'test@test.com',
    "password"      => "testing",
    "role"          => "1"
]);
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
$I->seeResponseContainsJson(['status' => 'success']);
$I->seeResponseContainsJson(['data' => [
    'first_name' => 'Test'
]]);
$I->seeInDatabase('user', [
    "first_name"    => "Test",
    "last_name"     => "Test",
    "email"         => 'test@test.com'
]);
```

Now this tests fails at affirming that status is success. Instead I see status failure and the reason comes back to me as `404 Route Not Found`. But when I make the same request using Postman, it runs just fine and a new user is created in the database.

I have inspected the routes.php file and it looks just fine to me. I have placed the user resource in it like so:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

Moreover I have other tests like:

```
<?php 


$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('create a new comment');
$I->useToken();
$I->sendPost('comments', [
    "document_id" => "1",
    "comment_type_id" => "1",
    "user_id" => "1",
    "body" => "Testing"
]);
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
$I->seeResponseContainsJson(['status' => 'success']);
$I->seeInDatabase('comment', [
    "document_id" => "1",
    "comment_type_id" => "1",
    "user_id" => "1",
    "body" => "Testing"
]);
```

And this is running and asserting just fine. But when I purposely make it miss a few fields in the `sendPost` method to test the validations in place, again the same issue -> `404 Route Not Found` which is pretty weird. This is happening with other tests too. Some say route not found as it is and some throw that exception when I am missing some arguments to make them fail somehow through validation. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

**codeception.yml**

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled: [Codeception\Extension\RunFailed]
modules:
    config: { Db: { dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=carparts', user: homestead, password: secret, dump: tests/_data/dump.sql } }
```

**api.suite.yml**

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Laravel5
        - Db
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://archive.app/api'
            curl:
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER: true
        - REST:
            url: /api/
            depends: PhpBrowser
    config:
        Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.testing
```

**ApiTester.php**

```
class ApiTester extends \Codeception\Actor
{
    use _generated\ApiTesterActions;

   /**
    * Define custom actions here
    */

    public function saveToken($response)
    {
        file_put_contents('tests/api/token', json_decode($response)->token);
    }

    public function saveSuperToken($response)
    {
        file_put_contents('tests/api/superToken', json_decode($response)->token);
    }

    public function saveFakeToken($response)
    {
        file_put_contents('tests/api/fakeToken', json_decode($response)->token);
    }

    public function useToken()
    {
        $I = $this;
        $I->haveHttpHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . file_get_contents('tests/api/token'));
    }

    public function useSuperToken()
    {
        $I = $this;
        $I->haveHttpHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . file_get_contents('tests/api/superToken'));
    }

    public function useFakeToken()
    {
        $I = $this;
        $I->haveHttpHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . file_get_contents('tests/api/fakeToken'));
    }
}
```

**--debug option output**

```
[Request headers] {"Authorization":"Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImNhcnBhcnRzIiwic3ViIjoxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9hcmNoaXZlLmFwcFwvYXBpXC9hdXRoZW50aWNhdGUiLCJpYXQiOjE0NTAwODg5NzMsImV4cCI6MTQ1MDE0Mjk3MywibmJmIjoxNDUwMDg4OTczLCJqdGkiOiIxOTM4YmU0OWZhZjIyMTE5ZjJhZDY0ZDAwOTJhZTExOSJ9.Gsc0Acxq7QPMOejMHRJ4yCYAhxnDUscGqo1-NbT7gIM"}
  [Request] POST /api/users {"first_name":"Test","last_name":"Test","email":"test@test.com","password":"testing","role":"1"}
  [Response] {"status":"error","data":[null],"errors":null,"message":"404 Route Not Found"}
  [Cookies] {"laravel_session":"eyJpdiI6Im03Smh5VUZJMEdJVUVjVDZxRlpzVVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWHF2aTQ5MXZWbnl2eU5OREc4cDhmOENEeUlGRzRKbVpuYXFQeW9WMlVzQjRUT2hTZldWVnJ4SmVFTEJ3Y1lKblwvQWlWalhWSkVEUW95b0t2QkxkTDJBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI2N2MwYmM3N2JjZTI5NWE2NjAyMWY3OWI3ZDJkMDQzNGU5ZTk2ODBkNmNiNmRhZWVhOTdlZmEzYWUyNDI4YzA3In0="}
  [Headers] {"Server":["nginx/1.8.0"],"Content-Type":["application/json"],"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"Connection":["keep-alive"],"Cache-Control":["no-cache"],"Date":["Mon, 14 Dec 2015 10:29:55 GMT"]}
  [Status] 200
```

Comment: What does your post raw data look like in Postman?

Comment: I am confused. How do I check that?

Comment: Do you have anything in your helper? What does your yaml file look like? Did you define sendpost in your helper and are you using the rest module?

Comment: Added all the extra information. :)

Comment: It seems for me as it was a problem with routes for testing environment. When you use Postman have you set environment to testing?  Are all your routes defined as you showed or maybe you defined them somehow depending on environment set?

Comment: There is only one route file and it has all the routes. I haven't changed any routes according to environment preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us a screen shot of Postman that works?
[image]

Comment: I am using the form-data for the body so when I switch to raw, I don't see anything. It is blank.

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause for this issue is that the Laravel5 module enabled in api.suite.yml

Laravel5 (and other framework modules) are not compatible with PhpBrowser and having both enabled is a very common issue.

`seeResponseCodeIs` method is provided by Laravel5, PhpBrowser and REST modules.
The client is shared between REST module and the module it depends on, but it is very likely that seeResponseCodeIs provided by Laravel5 is used by ApiTester.

The solution is to remove Laravel5 module from this suite.